# "Some are", or "some can be"?

Tags: verbs, usage

Do we say

> Gaps can be dangerous things, but some gaps **are** beneficial.

or

> Gaps can be dangerous things, but some gaps **can be** beneficial.

?

Answer (score 3):

Both versions are acceptable. The second puts slightly less stress on the outcome, but neither are very different.

First version says `some gaps` - so not all of them.

Second version says `can be` which again means 'not always' as well as containing `some gaps` meaning not all of them.